# "Поймать" ошибку цикла for

Tags: c#, исключения, for

Всем доброго времени суток!

Имеется цикл, который рано или поздно выдаст ошибку:

```
for (int i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            IWebElement boom = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content"));
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
```

Цикл как бы перебирает элементы с нужным id и далее проводит с ними определенный набор операций. Каждый раз кол-во данных элементов разное, поэтому предугадать момент, когда цикл сломается нельзя... или можно? :)

Каким образом можно отловить ошибку с поломанным циклом и продолжить работу? Брать весь блок в try-catch? Какое Exception брать в данном случае, если использовать try? Быть может, есть вариант без изобретения велосипедов?

Во время работы данного for происходит однократное(за один круг цикла) открытие нового окна, с переключением WebDriver на него:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Возможно, есть вариант отловить отсутствие нового окна? Ошибка вылетает сразу после данной строки. На данном элементе:

```
IWebElement beornottobe = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Be-be"));
```

Но после идёт еще не малая часть кода...

Comment: В вашем примере кода нет строки driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last()); когда происходит переключение на другое окно? beornottobe должен находиться в этом окне? В вашем тексте нет информации о том, что за исключение вылетает. Как вы думаете вам помогут если не ясно что вы вообще делаете. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, покажите код, покажите пример разметки, которую вы проверяете, а так же напишите что за исключение вы получаете и что хотите сделать. Иначе вас очень сложно понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какое Exception брать в данном случае, если использовать try?

В документации [сказано](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElement.htm) что это будет [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_NoSuchElementException.htm).

```
for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
    IWebElement boom;
    try {
        boom = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException) {
        break; //прерываем цикл в случае ошибки
    }
...
```

Comment: почему бы не ловить `Exception`?

Comment: @Flippy проброс исключения